# When I am installing tomcat 7 in ubuntu 16.04 I got this error

Tags: servlets

When I am installing tomcat 7 in ubuntu 16.04 I got this error

> invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.
>   ● tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-05-29 00:33:24 IST; 6ms ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
>     Process: 972 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> May 29 00:33:24 developer-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
>   May 29 00:33:24 developer-HP-Notebook tomcat7[972]:  * no JDK or JRE found - please set JAVA_HOME
>   May 29 00:33:24 developer-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   May 29 00:33:24 developer-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
>   dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    tomcat7
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Either Java is not installed or you have the environment variable JAVA_HOME not pointed to it. Check for existence of java on your system, by executing following command in a terminal:

```
 java -version
```

Install Java, by either downloading a jdk or jre from oracle java: https://java.com/.

Or just run:

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: in my system java is installed  and it also define environment variable JAVA_HOME

Comment: Well, at least the installation script of the tomcat package does not recognize the env var.  What is the output from `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: [/usr/lib/jvm/default-java]

Comment: Did you configure that after you tried to install tomcat? Then this should now work: `systemctl start tomcat7`